# Limit Points and Convergence of Sequences.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

Let $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$). A point $p \in \mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{R}$  ) is called a limit point of $E$, if $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists z \in E$ such that
$0 < |z − p| < \epsilon$.
Note that $p$ need not be in $E$.

**Theorem 1.1**.

A point $p \in \mathbb{R}$ is a limit point of $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ **if and only if** there exists a
sequence ($p_n$) in $E$ s.t. $p_n \rightarrow p$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and $p_n \not= p$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

My attempt:

$\Rightarrow$ direction

Since $p$ is a limit point $\forall \epsilon_n > 0$ which we choose to be $\frac{1}{n}$, $\exists z_n \in E$ such that
$0 < |z_n − p| < \epsilon_n \Rightarrow 0 < |z_n − p| < \frac{1}{n}$ . By simple sandwiching since $\frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

$z_n \rightarrow p$ . So we have found a sequence $z_n$ which tends to $p$

$\Leftarrow $ direction

If $p_n$ is a sequence which tends to $p$  $\forall \epsilon >0 $ $\exists N_\epsilon \in \mathbb{N}$

s.t 
$\forall n  \geq N_\epsilon$
$|p_n - p| <\epsilon$

$\Rightarrow $ $\forall \epsilon >0 $ $\exists p_{N_\epsilon} \in E$ 
s.t 
$|p_{N_\epsilon} - p| <\epsilon$ (the whole sequence was supposed to be contained in $E$) 
So $p$ is a limit point

$\square$

Both directions are fine?

Answer (score 1):

Both directions seem to be fine.